# Should the nix, nix-shell and nixos tags be merged?

Tags: discussion

At present there are several "nix" tags on the [cardano.se] site.

- Nix (34 questions)
- Nix-shell (23 questions)
- Nixos (5 questions)

For the sake of easier searching, I suggest that we merge and synonym the tags so that all three become `nixos`

**What's the community opinion?**

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

This is a good idea as the questions all relate to parts of NixOS

Answer (score 0):

## No

They are better as separate tags.

Comment: not a vote for "no", but I assume nix-shell and nixos questions should be different enough to warrant separate tags.